# ¿Como eliminar una propiedad de un Objeto?

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un Objeto que deseo eliminarle una propiedad

```
miObjeto = {
   propiedad1: "valor propiedad 1",
   propiedad2: "valor propiedad 2",
   propiedad3: "valor propiedad 3"
}
```

lo que deseo es eliminar la propiedad `propiedad2` del objeto `miObjeto`, ¿Como lo hago?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
delete miObjeto.propiedad2;
// ó,
delete miObjeto['propiedad2'];
// ó,
var prop = "propiedad2";
delete miObjeto[prop];
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
miObjeto = {
   propiedad1: "valor propiedad 1",
   propiedad2: "valor propiedad 2",
   propiedad3: "valor propiedad 3"
}

delete miObjeto['propiedad2'];
```